# May tags ms-excel and excel be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Is there any difference in meaning between the tags: [ms-excel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel) (55 uses) and [excel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) (4 uses)?

From what I researched at the [four questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) with [excel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) I thought there was no difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've added a synonym - feel free to vote for it.

Comment: Ian, as a mod you don't have to go through the approval process.  Use the link at http://gis.stackexchange.com/admin/create-tag-synonym instead.  BTW, I reversed the direction, making [tag:excel] the master, because "ms-excel" always makes me stop and think about what *other* excel we're attempting to distinguish with it!

Comment: That makes more sense now I think about it - but others seemed to prefer ms-excel. Thanks for the link I'd missed that.

Comment: @whuber I tried following your link but only got a 404 Page Not Found - does it only accessible to Community Moderators rather than those with Moderator Privileges?

Comment: @Poly Yes, unfortunately that's only for mods.